# Integration AngularJS with Ratchet.js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build an app with [RatchetJS](http://goratchet.com/) (the mobile framework, not the websocket server, ie. goratchet.com !!) and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) (v1.5.8). My question relates to project organization, routing and page loading.

What should handle routing if i want ratchet transitions to play nicely with angular js routing and controllers ? Here is what i have so far.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Application">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MyApplication</title>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet CSS -->
    <link href="css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="css/ratchet-theme-ios.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <!-- <link href="css/ratchet-theme-android.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet JS -->
    <script src="js/ratchet.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="view" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The angular JS app file.**

```
'use strict';
(function() {

    var Application = angular.module('Application', ['ngRoute']);

    Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'DefaultController',
                    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                })
                .when('/pages/chat.html', {
                    controller: 'ChatController',
                    templateUrl: '/pages/chat.html',
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectUrl: '/' })
            ;

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

    Application.controller('DefaultController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {
        $scope.title = "Grettings";
    }]);

    Application.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Chat view";
    }]);

})();
```

There are also two files in `/pages/...` folder (`home.html` and `chat.html`). The home.html contains a link looking like:

```
<a data-ignore="push" href="/pages/chat.html">Go to chat</a>
```

If i use `data-ignore="push"` the page gets loaded, but by angular (so no ratchet transitions. **Without it**, of course, the page gets loaded by Ratchet but AngularJS does not catch the route and the controller is never called...

Providing i want to use ratchet for transitions. How should i handle my architecture / routing ?

Answer (score -1):

Ratchet is not meant for transitions or what you are refering to.

It is meant as a WebSocket for PHP the problem that you are having is clientside pageloading, so try adding more information about your angular install.

Comment: http://goratchet.com/ is more a CSS js/css UI/UX framework... nothing to do with websockets.. or ? It does provide transitions.

Comment: You are talking about the other Ratchet (socketo.me)